# HTML Form with two 'Submit' inputs acting strangely

Tags: html, forms, submit-button

I have a form with two submit buttons. That's not the issue; I can do that just fine. Let's cut to the chase. Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Assume there's a lot more document here. -->
<form action="place1.html" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Place 1!" />
    <input type="submit" formaction="place2.html" value="Go to Place 2!" />
</form>
```

The first button works completely as intended. The second button is the weird - it actually goes to place1.html UNLESS you click on the rightmost ten or so pixels - then it goes to place2.html. Does anyone know what's going on here? I've tested it on Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. Is it my HTML? The browser? My computer?

**Update**
Alright, so I disabled the CSS on the page - this made no difference. There wasn't any CSS targeting inputs of any kind, anyway. I also removed the `action` attribute from the `form` tag and added a `formaction` attribute to the first submit button, as per Agony's suggestion - no dice. :( I am going to keep that, though, because it feels cleaner.

Here's a little more of my environment. I actually have three buttons contained in two fieldsets contained in one form. Now, it might be the CSS on the divs.

```
<form id="server-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="custID" value="@Model.CustomerID" form="server-form" />

    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fieldset One</legend>
            <!-- Content goes here -->
            <p><input type="submit" formaction="/page1.html" value="Go to Page 1" />
            <input type="submit" formaction="/page2.html" value="Go to Page 2" /></p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

<div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fieldset Two</legend>
        <!-- More and different content goes here -->
        <p><input type="submit" formaction="/page3.html" value="Go to Page 3" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Why didn't I reveal this before? I wanted to keep the situation as general as possible to see if there were any stupid things I was just missing before narrowing it to my specific instance.
If it makes a difference, I'm also using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Razor, but I don't think that should.

Comment: When you say it behaves differently depending on where you click, I think css. Can you link to anything live to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @erquhart Unfortunately, no; the examples I have are all local for my job. :( I'll disable the CSS and see what that does, though.

Comment: @erquhart Updated the post - there's some CSS in there, mostly floats.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a problem with this using Chrome, Firefox, or IE, but I would suggest setting your HTML up like this.

```
<form>
<input type="submit" formaction="place1.html" value="Go to Place 1!" />
<input type="submit" formaction="place2.html" value="Go to Place 2!" />
</form>
```

If possible. Otherwise, I would want to see the CSS behind it to determine why your second button is like that.

Comment: I added an update - please see the original post if you want.